# Port java library to wasm with TeaVM

Tags: javascript, java, libraries, teavm

I made a simple Java library and now I would like to compile it to WASM and port to javascript. I'm having really hard time figuring out how to do it with TeaVM. I found this thread

https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm/issues/176

but their approach seems extremely over-engineered. Is there really no simple way to port library functions to JS? Why does everything have to be done with `@JSBody`. Maybe there is some better tool than TeaVM?

Comment: Java and Javascript have no relationship. Converting a program from Java to javascript is a very involved process, to do it right.

Comment: @NomadMaker I know that much. But when I ported my C library to JS, I used Emscripten which did 100% of the work for me. I'm sure that there is a nice way to do it in Java as well

Comment: I don't know. I do believe that C is much closer to javascript than java is.

Comment: @NomadMaker well, actually, Java is much closer to JS than C. Both Java and WASM run in VM and both support garbage collection. In fact, the translation from JVM bytecode to WASM is pretty much 1:1 conversion. Only problem is that Java-to-WASM seems to have crappy tool support